# What is the time-complexity of this equality operator between two containers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, equality

I'm testing my understanding of complexity and want to verify my answer.

I have an equality operator between two containers of the same type. My algorithm iterates over the `lhs` (aka `this`) and tests for item containment in `rhs`. Subsequently, the algorithm iterates over the `rhs` and tests for item containment in `lhs` (aka `this`). At any time, if item is not in the other contain the algorithm `breaks` with a `false`.

So, I think that the minimum complexity is constant time `O(1)`, since when `lhs` and `rhs` are different sizes the result is false.

I think that the maximum complexity is `O(2n^2)` for the edge case when the test for containment is always last for every element of both `lhs` and `rhs` iterations.

Is this right? Are there nuances that I have missed or misunderstood?

Here's an implementation of my algorithm. They are custom types but the algorithm should be readable.

```
    bool LibrdfModel::operator==(LibrdfModel &rhs) {
        /**
         * Note on complexity - this algorithm is quite expensive.
         * First, if not same size, then return false. So the rest is assuming the size of lhs and rhs are equal.
         * iterate over lhs. For each of the n elements element we search through n rhs --> n^2
         * Then we iterate over rhs. For each of the n elements we search through n lhs elements --> n^2
         * So we have O(2n^2)
         */

        // we first try comparing size. If they are not equal, then the models are not equal
        if (size() != rhs.size())
            return false;

        // if they are the same size, we need a more expensive operation to compare the models
        // No equals operator exists for a model so we use this strategy:
        // Convert this and that to a stream. Iterate over each stream
        // checking if all statements in this are in that and all
        // statements in that are in this. Then this == that.
        bool all_this_in_rhs = true;
        bool all_rhs_in_this = true;
        LibrdfStream this_stream = toStream();
        {
            int count = 0;

            while (!this_stream.end()) {
                LibrdfStatement statement = this_stream.getStatement();
                // check statement is in other model
                bool contains_statement = rhs.containsStatement(statement);
                if (!contains_statement) {
                    all_this_in_rhs = false;
                    break;
                }
                this_stream.next();
                count++;
            }
        }

        LibrdfStream rhs_stream = rhs.toStream();
        {
            int count = 0;
            while (!rhs_stream.end()) {
                LibrdfStatement statement = rhs_stream.getStatement();
                // check statement is in other model
                bool contains_statement = rhs.containsStatement(statement);
                if (!contains_statement) {
                    all_rhs_in_this = false;
                    break;
                }
                rhs_stream.next();
                count++;
            }
        }
        return all_this_in_rhs && all_rhs_in_this;
    }
```

Comment: Looks right, although `O(2n^2)` is just `O(n^2)`.  Those constant really don't matter in the scheme of things.

Comment: though you could make it potentially twice as fast on average by not calculating `all_rhs_in_this` when `all_this_in_rhs` os already `false`

Comment: O(2 n^2) is not a meaningful thing because factors are explicit excluded from O notation. So what you should use O(n^2).

Comment: And you ignore the complexity of he container operations. For example there are containers which have a O(log(n)) contains operation, even in worst case. The would reduce the complexity to O(n log(n)).

Comment: There's a nasty typo in the second loop. Don't copy and paste, write a function.

Comment: Right you are - I've just modified this to use a OOP wrapper around a C library. In short, my tests would have picked it up eventually but thanks for the heads up. Nasty indeed.

Comment: This does not handle values occurring more than once meaningfully: 001 ≠ 011. Where that is OK, it still **needs** to be documented.

Comment: i mean we can't tell the time complexity from the code provided because we do not know the time complexity of  LibrdfModel::containsStatement. If that is O(n) that this is O(n^2) but for all we know they are hash tables in which case this is O(n).

Comment: `containsStatement` is a simple find operation. Go through all the elements from index 0 and return true if found, false otherwise.